# ASP.NET MVC updating the View from my Controller via a time interval event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been working with my ASP.NET application and made some significant changes to it. When I first started out I wanted to know how do I update my view from the controller. Bit with the thanks of the incredible people who guided me I was able to learn about Ajax and how to send update data via client. I did this by hitting a refresh button I created.

But now I want the data to be updated after a certain amount of time has passed (3 minutes, as an example). How do I go about in setting something like this up? Do I set that up inside the Ajax.BeginForm function or is it done via JavaScript? I would like to know your input on this.

**My Model:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Portfolio.Models
{
    public class HomeViewModel
    {
        public List<User> User = new List<User>();
    }
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
using Portfolio.Models;
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Portfolio.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public HomeViewModel model = new HomeViewModel();
        Timer Timer = new Timer();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ModelState.Clear();

            model.User.Add(new User() { Name = "A", Email = "a@email.com", Date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1) });
            model.User.Add(new User() { Name = "B", Email = "b@email.com", Date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2) });
            model.User.Add(new User() { Name = "C", Email = "c@email.com", Date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3) });

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
               return PartialView("_FooView", model);
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

**My View:**

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }
    @model Portfolio.Models.HomeViewModel

 @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    new AjaxOptions
    {
      HttpMethod = "get",
      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
      UpdateTargetId = "FooView"
    }))
  {
    <button type:"submit" value:"Refresh/>

  }
@Html.Partial("_FooView", Model)
```

**My newly created Partial View:**

```
@model Portfolio.Models.HomeViewModel
<div id="FooView">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.User.Count; i++)
        {
            <form>
                <div id="Name">@Model.User[i].Name</div>
                <div id="Email">@Model.User[i].Email</div>
                <div id="Date">@Model.User[i].Date</div>
            </form>
            <div>---------------------
        </div>
        }    
    </div>
```

Comment: Its not clear what your trying t do here. What is your `private void Timer_Elapsed()` and what are you expecting that to do?

Comment: If you're trying to have the page refreshed automatically then you'll need to have the browser make that request, so you'll need to use a JaveScript timer.

Comment: @StephenMuecke what that elapsed event does is just calls the Action that sets the new values and returns to the View the new model

Comment: @jmcilhinney no, the only thing I am trying to do is just update the values. I am not trying refresh the page

Comment: No it does not. You seem to be misunderstanding how the web works. Your browser makes a request to the server and the server sends back a response (your view). It is then disconnected from the server. The browser has no knowledge of what is happening on the server after that

Comment: If you want to update the view, then your browser needs to make another request to the server to get the new data/view (e.g. by making a redirect, or by using ajax if you want to stay on the same page)

Comment: By "refresh the page" I mean send data from the server to the client. The server can't just initiate sending data to a browser that didn't ask for it. Can you imagine how much garbage you'd be sent by web sites if that was the case? If anything is to be displayed in the browser then the browser has to ask for it. Your page has to make an AJAX call to the server to execute a new action. That action can then either return a partial view to replace part of your  page or JSON that you can use to update your HTML using JavaScript.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thank you for your prompt replies. I am still new to ASP.NET MVC so this all feels alien to me. Nevertheless I will do some research and figure out a way to modify my MVC code so that I am able to get the values I am so desperately trying to see updated on screen.

Comment: Here's something that might be useful as a start: https://app.pluralsight.com/player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m6-ajax&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building

Comment: you need to request each time you want from client(browser) not from server.

Comment: @all sorry for the late reply, busy Sunday. Thank you all for your help. I will look into the link you sent me. I am new to ASP.NET MVC as you can tell. Thank you for being so patient. You all have been a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setInterval and then submit the form using JavaScrip

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  setInterval(submitForm(), 180000); 
});

function submitForm() {
  $("#YOUR_FORM_ID").submit();
}
```

Set the id of the Ajax Form using the `htmlAttributes` on the `Ajax.BeginForm` using the syntax `new { id = "YOUR_FORM_ID" }`

Comment: Thanks a mil. Although I really do appreciate everyone involved in this. I did not see the id property for the form straight away. That was the missing piece.

Comment: one thing I noticed is that I am seeing that the whole websites reloads. I want only what is in the partial view to reload. Any thoughts on how should I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You speak of using ajax, so I'm guessing there is a JavaScript function you call on the button click? If so, try [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) (using jQuery here):

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  setInterval(ThatAjaxFunctionsName, 180000); // 180 seconds - 3 minutes
});
```

May need more details on said function though, I'm assuming it is just some function ThatAjaxFunctionsName() { } situation.

Comment: right now I dont have a javascript function. Its just that button you saw within my Ajax.Form method. I will try what you showed me.

Comment: ah, you're using Ajax.BeginForm / AjaxOptions. Honestly, I never did that and just created HttpGet/HttpPost methods in my controller to retrieve the data I was after and then accessed them via JavaScript.